# How Authorize attribute work in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I research about mvc3 and i read alot article or watch video on asp.net website.
After i have some knowledge about mvc3 and so i have question about **Authorize** attribute to authenticate user is login or not.
The default code when i create a page to authenticate user like this:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
                if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
                    && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
                {
                    return Redirect(returnUrl);
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

If i don't want to use Membership and FormsAuthentication (Don't say about windows authentication) to authorize for user.  So is there any way to create something to authenticate user and when i use **Authorize**
 attribute it will work like when i use **Membership and FormsAuthentication**. I don't know what Authorize attribute use to authenticate user is login or not, from that i can create a session or cookie by myself to authenticate user.  If my question not clear , please let me know!
Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is roll your own authorise attribute like this:

```
public class AuthorizeAttribute : System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute
{

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(System.Web.HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        //Put your authorisation check here
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        //put your redirect to login controller here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply me soon. Like you said i can't do something very very simple to authenticate user? For instance when user login i will create a session or cookie by myself that when i call Authorize attribute it will know user login or not. Or i have to use Formauthentication to authenticate user and after that Authorize attribute can work like Default.